# Linux bash script symlink with spaces

Tags: linux, bash, symlink, ln

I am trying to make a script which will find all the folders and files within a given hard drive. then i want to make the symlinks to another folder. However the ln command fails if the folder or file contains space, can someone help me to modify the ln -sf $MOVIE_FILE_LINKS -t $MOVIES_LIB command to make the folders with spaces work?
Thanks

```
#! /bin/bash
# Version: 2017.02.21

SRC="/mnt/hdd_1.5T
/mnt/hdd_4T"

MOVIES_TEXT="Movies.*"
MOVIES_LIB="/mnt/Library.Movies/"

rm -rf $MOVIES_LIB    #need more elegant solution
mkdir -p $MOVIES_LIB

clear

MOVIE_DIRS=$(find $SRC -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "$MOVIES_TEXT")
MOVIE_DIR_LINKS=$(find $MOVIE_DIRS -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort | awk '$0 !~ last "/" {print last} {last=$0} END {print last}')
MOVIE_FILE_LINKS=$(find $MOVIE_DIRS -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.*")

echo "$MOVIE_DIR_LINKS"
#ln -sf $MOVIE_LINKS $MOVIES_LIB;
echo "$MOVIE_FILE_LINKS"
#ln -sf $MOVIE_FILE_LINKS -t $MOVIES_LIB;
```

Comment: Escape the blanks with a backslash or put the argument into double quotes.

Comment: Double quotes are not working in such way:   ln -sf ""$MOVIE_FILE_LINKS"" -t $MOVIES_LIB;

Comment: `ln -sf "$MOVIE_FILE_LINKS" -t "$MOVIES_LIB"`?

Comment: Already tried. This will pass just one item from the $MOVIE_FILE_LINKS - and still problem with spaces.-However thanks

Comment: Ah, I see, there are multiple files in there... you need an array, I'd say.

Comment: What is the meaning of pass with `awk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `find`'s `-exec` action:

```
find $MOVIE_DIRS -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ln -sf -t $MOVIES_LIB {} +
find $MOVIE_DIRS -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.*" -exec ln -sf -t $MOVIES_LIB {} +
```

Comment: This solution seem to be perfect- just testing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: one small thing here: the links will create all the subfolders + unfortunately the main folder also will be created as symlink - hence the library folder has that folder as well-kind of doubled.  I will try to remove somehow with scripting...no idea yet

Comment: Add `-mindepth 1` for preventing main folder in find result